# Counting specific subgraphs

Tags: algorithms, graphs, counting

For a given undirected graph **G**, I want to count all the subgraphs **H** that satisfies the following conditions:

- **H.V** = **G.V** (The subgraph will containt all the original graph nodes)
- **H** is connected

(Note: I don't care if two subgraphs are isomorphic)

The graphs which I will be working with will have **|G.V| <= 15**

Comment: Are you interested in the number of *nonisomorphic* graphs or the total of all (connected) subgraphs? In either case, you could help us to help you by describing what you've tried so far.

Comment: What do you mean by "**H.V**" and "**G.V**"?

Comment: By `H.V` do you mean the vertices of `H`?

Comment: The subgraph will containt all the original graph nodes

Comment: Still it would be nice to answer to comments by editing the question.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is known as counting the number of connected spanning subgraphs, and is pretty hard even for restricted classes of graphs. See [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3465/complexity-of-counting-all-connected-subgraphs) on cstheory.

The number of connected spanning subgraphs of a graph $G$ equals $T_G(1,2)$, where $T_G$ is the Tutte polynomial of $G$ (this is mentioned in one of the answers to the linked question). Hence [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0711.2585v1.pdf) of Björklund et al., which shows how to compute said polynomial in vertex-exponential time (i.e., $\exp O(n)$), gives us hope, since in your case $n$ is pretty small ($n \leq 15$).